# Prismy deploy command throws Invalid Version error

Tags: graphql, graphcool, prisma

I'm just following the basic prisma.io get started guide (https://www.prisma.io/docs/quickstart/)

When I want to run the deploy command (*prisma deploy*) I keep getting this error:

> !    Invalid Version: 1.1
>
> Get in touch if you need help: https://www.prisma.io/forum/
>
> To get more detailed output, run $ export DEBUG="*"

There seem to be no results related to this on Google or Prisma's forums.

Answer (score 3):

There was an issue in the initial version of the 1.10 CLI. please update the CLI and try again :-)

Sorry about the trouble!